# The Quest For My Northern Home

Tags: knowledge, story, animals

I am a hybrid, a part of two wholes

I became accomplished and then I was sold

But enroute to my new home

Down I rocketed to the frozen bowl

Encased in iron for three days

I lost the courage I had

Found at last by the land's man

I soon began to heal

Never before had I had such love

Harshness was all I had before

Just as was better, I was spirited away

To the home that was meant

Tis' place wasn't for me, wanted back north

With a friend's help, escaped, said up there I still had a chance

City streets and scraps, smarter than the rest

Then trapped again, and saved by me recent friend

Over summer whales we soon went

My trek was on again

Sadly released to the wilderness

Over places high and low

Eating hunted raw, facing ice and snow

Earned a love in a clever fight

Sadly soon she died

After endless time I was there

Back to my loving life

Killed my old enemy

Who had tormented me

And lived happily on at last

Who I am, and what lands have I journeyed?

And explain the title please!

Hint:

> It’s a book.

Comment: Alexander Hamilton? Oh wait, “killed my old enemy,” not “killed by my enemy.” Nevermind, derp :)

Comment: I was gonna write Frankenstein's monster but then saw the animals tag. Nevermind, derper :)

Comment: Any hint for this?

Comment: To me this seems to be rot13(n zvk bs GJB obbxf - ovgf erfrzoyr Pnyy bs gur Jvyq ol Wnpx Ybaqba, juvyr bguref erfrzoyr nabgure bs uvf obbxf, Juvgr Snat.) I got most of the way through writing up an answer but it just didn't seem to be pulling together nicely enough in the end... I hope I'm wrong! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it

> Kavik the Wolf Dog

The Story...

> Kavik is a wolf-dog (two parts) raised for sled-dog racing. Sold off and crashed in a plane. Drama ensues with discovery, young boy affection, and final 'escape' back to the North.
> iirc, the lands include Northwest America - Alaska to Seattle and back.

The Title...

> Kavik's quest to return the 2,000 miles home to Alaska and his beloved Andy.

A good story for young and old.

Comment: I could, but that isn't exactly what you asked for. ;) You sure you want me to spoil the story for everyone? I hope curiosity would lead readers to the book.

Comment: Well, it's not really a riddle, it is just familiarity with the story. The tags were important to frame my recall, and the key phrases for me were "Down I rocketed to the frozen bowl; Encased in iron for three days; I lost the courage I had." That was familiar enough to remind me about the book as these are three important points in the story - two events and one theme. I just had to think through the rest of your description and the story fit. Well done on your description - a worthy, if condensed, retelling.